# Replacing or substituting a large number of if..else statements that have specific ranges

Tags: c++

My input is a range of positive integer values between 0 to 200, and I have to classify each value between ranges:0-24, 25-49, 50-74, 75-99, 100-124, 125-149, 150-174 and 175-200 and then output how many values lie is what range. The values are stored in a text file(TextScores.txt) separated with commas. Here is the code.

```
ifstream file;
string x;
int y,j;
int count[8]={0};
j=0;
file.open("C:\\Users\\USER\\Desktop\\TestScores.txt");
while(getline(file,x,','))
{
  y = stoi(x);
  if(y<=24)
  {
      count[0]++;
  }
  else
  if (y>=25 && y<=49)
  {
      count[1]++;
  }
  else
  if (y>=50 && y<=74)
  {
      count[2]++;
  }
  else
  if (y>=75 && y<=99)
  {
      count[3]++;
  }
  else
  if (y>=100 && y<=124)
  {
      count[4]++;
  }
  else
  if (y>=124 && y<=149)
  {
      count[5]++;
  }
  else
  if (y>=150 && y<=174)
  {
      count[6]++;
  }
  else
  if (y>=175 && y<=200)
  {
      count[7]++;
  }
}
for (int i=0; i<=7; i++)
{
    cout<<"Test scores between range "<<setw(3)<<j<<" to "
         <<setw(3)<<j+25<<" are "<<count[i]<<endl;
    j+=25;
}
```

Alternatives for the hefty amount of if..else statements can be:

```
y<=24 ? count[0]++ : y>=25 && y<=49 ? count[1]++ : y>=50 && y<=74 
count[2]++ : y>=75 && y<=99 ? count[3]++ : y>=100 && y<=124 ? count[4]++ :
y>=125 &&  y<=149 ? count[5]++ : y>=150 && y<=174 ? count[6]++ : count[7]++;
```

Or switch statements. Anyone got any other suggestions?

Note: I studied a little bit of range based for loops but I don't know precisely how to go about them in this situation. If anybody knows how to apply them on the problem specified it will be appreciated. I don't want to go into O.O.P. Thanks.

Comment: Your code would be a lot more readable if you introduced spaces around your operators. `<<setw(3)<<j+25<<" are "<<count[i]<<endl` ew

Comment: ++count[y / 25]; I guess you would still have to handle the situation when y = 200 separately.

Comment: The limits you are using look odd, shouldn't these look like `if(y<=24) /* ... */  else if (y>=25 && y<=49)` aso.?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ it doesn't matter, they're integer values. What I've written and what you've suggested both are correct.

Comment: @Mohsin I'm just saying it looks odd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that your ranges are exactly 25 apart. If you perform integer division on y, you can use that to index into your count array. There is a special case for y=200 because that would return 8, which is outside of your array size.

```
if (y >=0 && y < 200)
    ++count[y/25];
else if (y == 200)
    ++count[7];
```

---

As Richard Hodges states in his comment, a shorter, more idiomatic way of writing this would be just:

```
++count[ std::min(7, y/25) ];
```

You will need to include the algorithm header to access this function.

Comment: A related possiblity is to simply do `++count[y/25]`, then after all the values have been processed, `count[7] += count[8]`.

Comment: @Pete Becker Thanks for the logic fix. A simple ++count[y/25] might be dangerous, though. Wouldn't want to index out of the array due to erroneous data.

Comment: ++count[y == 200 ? 7 : y / 25]; Assuming all of the input data is correct, this seems like a nice one-liner.

Comment: @DeathTails - the problem statement says that the input ranges from 0 to 200, so there is no requirement to validate the input.

Comment: @PeteBecker Maybe I'm just paranoid, but I always like to have some form of error checking. I'll remove it though as my answer should be a solution to OP's question, and as it stands the error checking is not part of that.

Comment: std::min(7, y/25) would be idiomatic.

Comment: @RichardHodges Honestly, that's probably the best answer given the conditions.

Comment: @RichardHodges what if the ranges included the last digit as well for e.g. instead of 0-24,25-49...we had 0-25,26-50..so on, guess then you'd have to use the ifs or switch statements?

Comment: @Mohsin the answers would still be 25 apart, with the exception at the beginning. It would be something like min((y-1)/25,0)

Answer (score 2):

Define a struct

```
struct limit {
    int min;
    int max;
};
```

Then an array of that

```
struct limit limits[] = { {0, 24} {25, 49}, {50, 74} /* and so on */ };
```

Then loop over the array

```
while(getline(file,x,','))
{
  y = stoi(x);

  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(limits)/sizeof(limits[0]); i++) {
    if (y >= limits[i].min && y <= limits[i].max) {
       count[i]++;
    }
  }
}
```

Of course if the pairs are equidistant the array approach doesn't make sense. Go with my proposal if you need arbitrary integer ranges.

Also note that my proposal is plain C, opposed to the STL based answer from πάντα ῥεῖ.

Comment: One advantage to using an array of structures is that the array can be declared as "static const", so that it can be placed into read-only memory and directly accessed.  The variable doesn't need to be initialized at run-time like `std::map`.

Comment: Neither `getline` nor `stoi` is ANSI C.

Comment: Removed that remark. I wanted to distinguish the answer from the C++ approach.

Answer (score 1):

Besides that you can use a simple mathematical solution for your task, because there are apparently fixed steps of 25 (as was mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37885525/1413395)), in order to create a generic solution, you could use a `std::map<std::pair<int,int>,int>` that holds all the possible ranges as key values and run a loop for counting:

```
std::map<std::pair<int,int>,int> rangeCounts = 
     { { 0,  25 }, 0 ,
       { 24, 50 }, 0 ,
       { 49, 75 }, 0 ,
       // ...
       { 174, 200 }, 0 ,
     };

for(std::unordered_map<std::pair<int,int>,int>::iterator it = rangeCounts.begin();
    it != rangeCounts.end();
    ++it) {
    if(y > (it->first).first && y < (it->first).second)
        ++(it->second);
}
```

---

As a side note: Your current range delimiters look strange because of these overlapping lower and higher limits (if else cascade or not).

> and I have to classify each value between ranges:0-24, 25-49, 50-74, 75-99, 100-124, 125-149, 150-174 and 175-200 and then output how many values lie is what range.

The ranges (with my example) should look like:

```
std::map<std::pair<int,int>,int> rangeCounts = 
     { { 0,  24 }, 0 ,
       { 25, 49 }, 0 ,
       { 50, 74 }, 0 ,
       // ...
       { 175, 200 }, 0 ,
     };
```

and the range condition

```
    if(y >= (it->first).first && y <= (it->first).second)
```

---

> Note: I studied a little bit of range based for loops but I don't know precisely how to go about them in this situation.

These have nothing to do with your *range check* problem. A range based `for()` loop just allow to iterate over a containers contents based on the `std::begin()` and `std::end()` standard functions implicitely.

So a range based for loop implementation for my sample would look like

```
for(auto& entry : rangeCounts) {
    if(y >= entry.first.first && y =< entry.first.second)
        ++entry.second;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have a pattern in the if..else statements. You are making constant range size of 25. So, you should use the division by 25 to find the correct case to make the increment:
    while(getline(file,x,','))
    {
      y = stoi(x);
      count[y / 25]++;
    }

Comment: You missed the part where y == 200 count[7] should be used.